# Multiple checkbox value will show in textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code :

```
<body>
<div align="center">
<b>A<input type="checkbox" name="a" id="check" value="a"></b>
<b>B<input type="checkbox" name="b" id="check" value="a"></b>
<b>B<input type="checkbox" name="c" id="check" value="c"></b>
<b>D<input type="checkbox" name="d" id="check" value="d"></b>
</div>
<table align="center">
<tr>
<td>Text:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="text" id="text"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
```

I'm trying that: if (more than one) checkbox is selected (or checked) that value will be assigned into the checkbox like "abcd" or "acd" or "bd".For that I have written jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).click(function(){
if($("#check").attr('checked')){
    $("#text").val(("#check").val());
}
});
</script>
```

able to print one txtbox value at a time,but not able to put all checked value in the textbox at a time.
Where I am going wrong ??Any inputs will appreciated.

Comment: first of all you need to change the id's of checkboxes.. It should be unique, not the same.. Then you can change the selector #check with some common class name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may have not understood you correctly, but does this fiddle help you? http://jsfiddle.net/XwGJ9/1/

The change is the javascript:

```
var $textInput = $('#text');
var $checkBox = $('#checkboxes');

$('input').click(function(){
    populateTextInput();
});

function populateTextInput () {
    // empty text input
    $textInput.val('');

    // print out all checked inputs
    $checkBox.find('input:checked').each(function() {
        $textInput.val( $textInput.val() + $(this).val() );
    });
}
```

Edit: updated

Comment: thanks for your reply,but chkbox is not checked...it still assigns the value to textbox,any input on this regard + 1more thing->if one the combination(suppose "acd" or "cd" is checked)that will not repeat again.any inputs.....

Comment: Oh sorry, I dod not catch that. Will do some changes.

Comment: jonas, in that link it's working properly and i think ur coding is right,but somehow in my case still it isn't working;once it has shown "ISO-8859-1" character encoding error and in a simple jsp page,even I'm trying to run ur updated code,but not atall running.I'm using jquery-17.2.js.Any guess where I'm going wrong.

Comment: @Vivekanand: you need to make sure that, when you are copying from the fiddle to your editor, that a) the browser is UTF-8 b) that the editor is UTF-8, c) that the compiler reads UTF-8. I am no expert on this, but the main point is that you have to have ONE encoding all the way :)

Comment: onmore thing> suppose I'm selecting a,b,c or b,c checkbox,then it will show in another text box like "Apple,Bee,Citrus" or "Bee,Citrus"(here these values are not in checkbox input,i have to hardcode it)......any idea.

Comment: hi Jonas, when i'm trying to run this piece of code $(document).ready(function() { 
 $('.check').click(function(){
     $("#features").val('Start');
         $(".check").each(function(){
         if($(this).prop('checked')){
             $("#features").val($("#features").val() + $(this).data('name'));             
             }         
     });
 });​
}); not running properly,...any inputs

Comment: hi Jonas,once again calling you,what you solution is allright[ http://jsfiddle.net/XwGJ9/1/],suppose in this case B & D will be by default checked,then how to handle this...? any idea...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/XwGJ9/19/ you set them to checked and add a function call to document.ready.

Comment: thnks,suppose for corresponding values I want to show,...any inputs on this

Answer (score 3):

Use this code

```
$('.check').click(function(){
    $("#text").val('');
    $(".check").each(function(){
        if($(this).prop('checked')){

            $("#text").val($("#text").val()+$(this).val());
        }
    });
});​
```

​

With this HTML (use `class` instead of `id` for abcd)

```
<div align="center">
<b>A<input type="checkbox" name="a" class="check" value="a"></b>
<b>B<input type="checkbox" name="b" class="check" value="b"></b>
<b>B<input type="checkbox" name="c" class="check" value="c"></b>
<b>D<input type="checkbox" name="d" class="check" value="d"></b>
</div>
<table align="center">
<tr>
<td>Text:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="text" id="text"></td>
</tr>
</table>​
```

Also I encourage to use CSS instead of `align="center"`

[**See live, running demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/aLLx9/1/)

Comment: Thnks for your reply but Showing "ISO-8859-1" character encoding error while ruuning this code + not at all working this piece of code

Answer (score 1):

So I think you're wanting to append the values together in the textbox. In that case, do:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).click(function(){
if($("#check").attr('checked')){
    var textBoxVal = $("#text").val()+$("#check").val(); // Concatenate the existing textbox value with the checkbox value.
    // Load the resulting value into new var textBoxVal.
    $("#text").val(textBoxVal); // Load the new value into the textbox.
}
});
</script>
```

I used native JS just to make it clearer what I'm doing.

Comment: one more thing> suppose I'm selecting a,b,c or b,c checkbox,then the value will be shown in another text box like "Apple,Bee,Citrus" or "Bee,Citrus"(here these values are not in checkbox input,i have to hardcode it)......any idea.

Answer (score 1):

had used something like this.. might help you

```
var checkeditems = $('input:checkbox[name="check[]"]:checked')
                          .map(function() {
                                return $(this).val()
                           })
                            .get()
                            .join(","); 

 $("#text").val(checkeditems);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want no multiples of a,b,c,d at one time, the onclick is per checkbox

```
        var boxes = $("input:checkbox");
        boxes.each(function(idx,elem){
                elem.onclick=function(event){
                    var choices = "";
                    boxes.each(function(idx,elem){
                        choices += elem.checked ? elem.name:"";
                    });
                    $('#text').val(choices);
                }
        });
```